# present a sheet with tapping on HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making a music player and I want to be able to go back to the music controls with an `HStack` at the bottom of the screen. I'm currently trying to learn about swiftUI so I don't know much.

I have a list view and it show the library and I have a status at the bottom. when the user taps on the song the sheet comes up and they can dismiss it using a button or swiping it down. I want to bring the sheet up to control the music that is currently playing.

The problem is the HStack at the bottom doesn't come up and I don't know how to fix it

This is what I tried:

```
    @State private var isShowingItemSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                MusicSingleListView(song: library[0].song, 
                                    artist: library[0].artist, 
                                    artwork: library[0].artwork)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // plays and pauses the song
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 25)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .onTapGesture {
                sheet(isPresented: $isShowingItemSheet, content: {
                    MusicView(musicInfo: library[0])
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried:

```
    @State private var isShowingItemSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                MusicSingleListView(song: library[0].song, 
                                    artist: library[0].artist, 
                                    artwork: library[0].artwork)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // plays and pauses the song
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 25)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingItemSheet, content: {
                    MusicView(musicInfo: library[0])
            })
        }
    }
```

But still I can't make it work and the sheet does not come up.

this is the screenshot of the HStack:

[image: HStack at the bottom of the screen]

this is the sheet that I want to show:

[image: the MusicView]

the code of music view is not that complicated it gets an object like this:

```
class MusicInfo: Identifiable , Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MusicInfo, rhs: MusicInfo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.song == rhs.song && lhs.artist == rhs.artist && lhs.artwork == rhs.artwork
    }
    
    let song: String
    let artist: String
    let artwork: String

    init(song: String, artist: String, artwork: String) {
        self.song = song
        self.artist = artist
        self.artwork = artwork
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sheet shouldn’t be inside onTapGesture. In fact, I bet the compiler is warning you about an unused result. The onTapGesure should likely mutate `isShowingItemSheet`

Comment: You should start with the Apple SwiftUI tutorials, Views don’t belong inside actions/voids you can trigger it from there but not present it. You are also going to have issues with other basic principles such as not being able to observe a regular class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI, there is a difference between blocks that change state, and blocks that describe how your app's views change when that state changes.

For example, `onTapGesture` takes a block that executes code when tapped. That code can change state.

But the `sheet` modifier is a SwiftUI view modifier. Its block contains the view that should display when its boolean state is true.

So your modifiers might look something like:

```swift
.onTapGesture {
  // change the app state in response to user action
  isShowingItemSheet = true
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingItemSheet) {
  // display this sheet when the app's state says to do so
  MusicView(musicInfo: library[0])
}
```